# fortran arrays with cshift

Tags: arrays, fortran

the piece of code below is working fine although I'd like to use a more efficient code as I will deal with large arrays i.e. with implied-do loops maybe. It basically calculates the difference between each element of the array with the next circularly shifted one. Do you have any suggestions ? The shift must be an integer in that case.

```
do i = 1, nb_imp-1
  X_dist(:,i) = lattice_imp%x - cshift(lattice_imp%x, shift=i)
  Y_dist(:,i) = lattice_imp%y - cshift(lattice_imp%y, shift=i)
  Z_dist(:,i) = lattice_imp%z - cshift(lattice_imp%z, shift=i)
end do
```

`lattice_imp%x`,`y`,`z` are integer arrays and `X_dist` contains the difference between each circularly permuted element.

Comment: What is exactly meant by "better syntax"? Shorter? More run-time efficient? As it stands it is opinion based.

Comment: Were it not Fortran, I would recommend going to stackexchange code review, but Fortran is not very common there.

Comment: How about some declarations showing the types involved?  I'm having trouble deducing them from the code, and it makes a difference.

Comment: @VladimirF Yes, the most efficient as I will deal with large arrays

Comment: Then rewrite the question to clearly indicate that. And probably leave out the non-specific "better syntax".

Comment: @JohnBollinger the lattice_x,y,z are integer arrays (vector coordinates). What I want, is to create for instance X_dist which contains the difference between all circular permutations of the elements of lattice_x. I hope it's clearer.

Comment: @VladimirF Yup, done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For large arrays you might regret this implementation. You are cshift-ing some (large) arrays on every iteration of the loop which means every iteration of that loop causes the compiler to assign a temporary variable of length `SIZE(lattice_imp%x)`, assign the shifted values to it and then discard it. That is, if I'm reading your snippet correctly.

Exchanging that 3 assignments inside for a plain old `DO` loop over the elements of `lattice_imp%x` etc will give you faster code.

-- EDIT -- 
sorry. though it's a little tricky without any kind of context for the types/arrays. maybe:

```
do i = 1, nb_imp-1
   do j = 1, ubound(lattice_imp%x,1)
     k = mod(j + i, i) +1 ! or whatever the correct implementation for this shifted index is...
     X_dist(j,i) = lattice_imp%x(j) - lattice_imp%x(k)
     Y_dist(j,i) = lattice_imp%y(j) - lattice_imp%y(k)
     Z_dist(j,i) = lattice_imp%z(j) - lattice_imp%z(k)
  enddo
end do
```

Comment: Care to show some example of the code you have in mind?

Comment: @listless huh huh ok. But does it mean that intrinsic functions aren't that efficient when scaling up the array size ?

Comment: Moreover, performing a separate loop for each of X_Dist, Y_Dist, and Z_Dist might improve performance by allowing better use of the data cache.

Comment: @JohnBollinger ok then, is there any general kind of rule for this ? I mean better separate loops than nested ones ? Thanks.

Comment: In principle, the compiler is free to generate more efficient code than @listless describes, but in practice it probably doesn't.

Comment: it's not that the intrinsic functions arent efficient, it's just a matter of what they do. cshift necessarily creates an array of the same dimensions as %x because it doesnt know any better than to do so. I'm sure, if you had an array and you wanted a second array that was cshifted by some amount then the intrinsic function would be just as good as anything else. The problem you have here is that a circular shift is not a good way to implement this behaviour.

Comment: Efficiency for large computations is heavily impacted by cache locality.  It is far faster to perform an operation on operands that can be loaded from cache than on operands that must be loaded from main memory.  Therefore, it's usually best for efficiency to work on one chunk of contiguous data at a time.

Comment: @listless@John Ok cool thanks for your answers. It helps me to understand a bit more.